# Img added by Javascript showing 0x0 pixels

Tags: javascript, image, random, background, createelement

I'm trying to add the same small image multiple times to a canvass. It shows in Inspect Elements correctly, except that the images have 0x0 pixels (natural is 200x45 or something).

Here's the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var bgd1 = document.getElementById('background1'),
    bgd2 = document.getElementById('background2'),
    WIDTH,
    HEIGHT,
    nbgd1,
    nbgd2,
    bgd1imgs = [];

setBackgroundSize();
drawbgd1();

function setBackgroundSize() {
    WIDTH = document.documentElement.clientWidth,
    HEIGHT = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
    bgd1.setAttribute("width", WIDTH);
    bgd1.setAttribute("height", HEIGHT);
    bgd2.setAttribute("width", WIDTH);
    bgd2.setAttribute("height", HEIGHT);
}

window.addEventListener('resize', setBackgroundSize, false);


function addbgd1(){
    this.obj = document.createElement('img');
    this.obj.src = 'img/bgd1.png';
    this.obj.classList.add('bgd1img');
    this.obj.width = 100;
    this.obj.height = 22;
    this.obj.style.top = Math.floor((window.innerHeight * Math.random())) + 'px';
    this.obj.style.left = Math.floor((window.innerWidth * Math.random())) + 'px';
    bgd1.appendChild(this.obj);
}


function drawbgd1(){
    nbgd1 = Math.floor(WIDTH / 100);
    for(var i=0; i<nbgd1 ; i++){
        bgd1imgs.push(new addbgd1());
    }
}
});
```

Completely lost here. I've tried several variations of CSS but there's no difference.

Here's the CSS:

```
#background1{
    position:fixed;
    z-index:-20;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    background-color:#000;   
    overflow:hidden;
}

.bgd1img{
    z-index:180;
    visibility:visible;
    display:block;
    height:22px;
    width:100px;
    position:fixed;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: btw, I'm calling drawbgd1();

Comment: Please provide a **runnable** [mcve]

Comment: this is the complete

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution. Still don't know why the old one didn't work (should?)

This is my current solution:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var bgd1 = document.getElementById('background1'),
    bgd2 = document.getElementById('background2'),
    ctx1 = bgd1.getContext('2d'),
    WIDTH,
    HEIGHT,
    nbgd1,
    randtop =  [],
    randleft = [],
    bgd1imgs = [];



setBackgroundSize();    

function setBackgroundSize() {
    WIDTH = document.documentElement.clientWidth,
    HEIGHT = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
    bgd1.setAttribute("width", WIDTH);
    bgd1.setAttribute("height", HEIGHT);
    bgd2.setAttribute("width", WIDTH);
    bgd2.setAttribute("height", HEIGHT);
    nbgd1 = Math.floor(WIDTH / 100);
    for (var i=0;i<nbgd1;i++){
        randtop[i] =  Math.floor(window.innerHeight * Math.random());
        randleft[i] = Math.floor(window.innerWidth * Math.random());
    }
    drawbgd1(nbgd1,randtop,randleft);
}
window.addEventListener('resize', setBackgroundSize, false);

function addbgd1(randtop,randleft){
    newbgd1 = new Image();
    newbgd1.src = 'img/bgd1.png';
    newbgd1.classList.add('bgd1img');
    newbgd1.onload = function(){
        ctx1.drawImage(newbgd1,randleft,randtop,100,22);
    }
}

function drawbgd1(nbgd1,randtop,randleft){        
    for(var i=0; i<nbgd1 ; i++){
        bgd1imgs.push(new addbgd1(randtop[i],randleft[i]));
    }
}
});
```